# How to store Firebase Database bool value Locally - Flutter (Dart)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database, boolean

I am using Firebase Realtime Database and I have a bool value in the Database `Joined` which is by default false. In my app I change it to true and then I want to store that change locally using Shared Preferences (The Database's name is `People`):

```
//Reference Database
Query dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('People');
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('People');
```

```
onPressed: (BuildContext contex) async {
              //Here I initialize Shared Prefs
              SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
              //here I change the value
              People['Joined'] = true;
              //Now I setbool (save it)
              prefs.setBool("People['Joined']", People['Joined']);
              },
```

But for some reason it's still not saving the value and I'm not really sure what there is more to do...

What I've Tried:
I have tried to add this `_loadData` variable but it's iffy:

```
late SharedPreferences prefs;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        prefs = value;
      });
      //load data
      _loadData();
    });
  }

_loadData() async {
    bool joined = prefs.getBool("People['Joined']") ?? false;
  }
```

This is gettting the bool but when I implement it, it still doesn't work maybe I'm implementing it incorrectly

Comment: What have you done to verify whether the value has been set? Are you sure it's not getting saved and then overwritten? Also `setBool` is an asynchronous operation, so by not awaiting it you may be unwittingly reading the value before the save has been finalized.

Comment: Try add setState in onPressed because initState run before you press button.

Comment: I see no call to the Realtime Database API in the code you shared. If the problem requires the use of the Realtime Database, please edit your question to show the [minimal code that also uses that API and that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If the problem can also be reproduced without Realtime Database, but you just happen to be using RTDB, please remove the tag.

Comment: When I change the bool form false to true it changes everything to true how can I make each individual one true?

Answer (score 0):

im refer to this document https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences, maybe you can access your data in local storage like this :

```
late SharedPreferences prefs;

@override
  void initState() async {
    super.initState();
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool joined = prefs.getBool("People['Joined']") ?? false;
    print(joined);
  }
```

Comment: When I change the bool form false to true it changes everything to true how can I make each individual one true?

Comment: maybe you can set different flag for each individual components that you mean.